# Adding image to project description in google code

Tags: google-code

I want to update a background image in google code projects.I searched their wiki, it talks about pointing image to an external world.Is there anyway we can upload the image to google code and provide a link?

Comment: It would be good for you to change the correct answer on this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution.First you need to upload the image to 'Download' area.After that, give the image url like this.

`<img src="http://yourgoogleproject.googlecode.com/files/name of your image.PNG" alt="Logo"/>`
You have to paste the above code inside apostrophe(') and end with apostrophe and can paste this in project description of your project summary tab.(I have just added here, in my case)

The file uploaded will go under 'files' folder of your project automatically.

Comment: Wiki mark-up means you don't need the full html. Just add line: `http://yourgoogleproject.googlecode.com/files/name of your image.PNG`

Answer (score 4):

This answer is no longer correct.  Google Code [removed the downloads option](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-change-to-google-code-download-service.html) in May 2013, due to misuse.  You can, as they suggest, move your files to Google Drive and link to them from there, which is fine for project downloads, but for items such as images in wiki pages or the project home page, I recommend checking the images into your source repository and linking to them.  For example, ig you use a [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com) repository and your files are checked into *docs/images*, then:

```
http://yourproject.googlecode.com/hg/yourproject/docs/images/logo.png
```

should work.